# Go to next step when fieldset is validated

Tags: javascript, jquery

The form is moving to next step even when it is not validated i want the form to be validated before it moves to next step.It gets validated when i click submit so only the last fieldset get validated. How can I enable query validation on click of next button.

```js
$("#formValidate").validate({
  rules: {
    user_name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10
    },

    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    },
    name1: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    },
    name2: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5
    },
    usr_email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },

    cemail1: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    cemail2: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    cemail3: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    cpassword: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      equalTo: "#password"
    },
    web: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    },
    crole: "required",
    ccomment: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 15
    },
    cgender: "required",
    cagree: "required",
    tel: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      phone: true

    },
    cphone1: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      digits: true

    },
    cphone2: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      digits: true

    },
    cphone3: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      digits: true

    },

    fees: "required",
    Student_Strength: "required",
    faculty_Strength: "required",
  },
  //For custom messages
  messages: {
    user_name: {
      required: "Please enter a name",
      minlength: "Enter at least 10 characters",
      digits: false,

    },
    name: {
      required: "<p class='val'>This field is required</p>",
      minlength: "<p class='val'>Enter at least 5 characters</p>",

    },
    name1: {
      required: "<p class='val'>This field is required</p>",
      minlength: "<p class='val'>Enter at least 5 characters</p>",

    },
    name2: {
      required: "<p class='val'>This field is required</p>",
      minlength: "<p class='val'>Enter at least 5 characters</p>",

    },
    web: "Please enter your website",
    tel: "Please enter a valid phone number",
    cphone1: "<p class='val'>Please enter a valid phone number</p>",
    cphone2: "<p class='val'>Please enter a valid phone number</p>",
    cphone3: "<p class='val'>Please enter a valid phone number</p>",

    fees: "we think you forget to mention the fees",
    Student_Strength: "we think you forget to mention the student strength",
    faculty_Strength: "we think you forget to mention the faculty strength",
    cemail1: "Please enter a valid email",
    cemail1: "<p class='val'>Please enter a valid email</p>",
    cemail2: "<p class='val'>Please enter a valid email</p>",
    cemail3: "<p class='val'>Please enter a valid email</p>",
  },
  errorElement: 'div',
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var placement = $(element).data('error');
    if (placement) {
      $(placement).append(error)
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
    }
  }
});
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')'
      });
      next_fs.css({
        'left': left,
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'left': left
      });
      previous_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
  return false;
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  var current = 1;

  widget = $(".step");
  btnnext = $(".next");
  btnback = $(".previous");
  btnsubmit = $(".submit");

  // next button click action
  btnnext.click(function() {
    if (current > 1) {
      current = current - 2;
      if (current < widget.length) {
        $('.basic').validate;
        widget.not(':eq(' + (current++) + ')').hide();
        setProgress(current);
      }
    }
    hideButtons(current);
  })


  // Back button click action
  btnback.click(function() {
    if (current > 1) {
      current = current - 2;
      if (current < widget.length) {
        widget.show();
        widget.not(':eq(' + (current++) + ')').hide();
        setProgress(current);
      }
    }
    hideButtons(current);
  })

  // Submit button click
  btnsubmit.click(function() {
    alert("Submit button clicked");
  });

  $('.form').validate({ // initialize plugin
    ignore: ":not(:visible)",
    rules: {
      name: "required"
    },
  });

});



// Hide buttons according to the current step
hideButtons = function(current) {
  var limit = parseInt(widget.length);

  $(".action").hide();

  if (current < limit) btnnext.show();
  if (current > 1) btnback.show();
  if (current == limit) {
    btnnext.hide();
    btnsubmit.show();
  }
}
```

```css
/* form */

#formValidate {
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 130%;
}
#formValidate fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#formValidate fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #056eba;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}
/*marking active/completed steps*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #056eba;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/additional-methods.js"></script>
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form class="col s12 formValidate" id="formValidate" method="post" action="register.php" name="regForm">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active step">Basic Information</li>
    <li class="step">Additional Information</li>
    <li class="step">Details</li>
    <li class="step">Additional Contact Information</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset class="basic">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">business</i>
        <input id="full_name" type="text" length="150" name="user_name" data-error=".errorTxt1">
        <label for="full_name" data-success="Perfect!">Please Let us know your name*</label>
        <div class="errorTxt1 right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" name="next" class="butt next action-button right" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="inc">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select name="course" data-error=".errorTxt7" multiple>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your course</option>
          <option value="1">Arts</option>
          <option value="2">Science</option>
          <option value="3">Commerce</option>
        </select>
        <label>What courses does your university offer*</label>
        <div class="errorTxt7 right"></div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <input type="button" name="previous" class="butt previous action-button" value="Previous" />

    <input type="button" name="next" class="butt next action-button right" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">assignment</i>
        <input id="fees" name="fees" type="number" placeholder="10000" step="100" min="100" data-error=".errorTxt8" class="validate" />
        <label for="fees">Approximated Academic Fees*</label>
        <div class="errorTxt8 right"></div>
      </div>

    </div>



    <input type="button" name="previous" class="butt previous action-button" value="Previous" />

    <input type="button" name="next" class="butt next action-button right" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>


    <div class="row">

      <label>
        Please Let us know some additional contact details*
      </label>
      <table class="highlight">
        <th>
          Contact details
        </th>

        <tr>
          <td class="responsive-table">Contact Person
            <td class="responsive-table">Phone number
              <td class="responsive-table">E-mail
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Administrator" length="120" class="validate" data-error=".errorTxt17" name="name" />
            <div class="errorTxt17"></div>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number" length="15" name="cphone1" class="validate" data-error=".errorTxt11" />
              <div class="errorTxt11"></div>
              <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" length="80" name="cemail1" class="validate" data-error=".errorTxt12">
                <div class="errorTxt12"></div>
        </tr>


      </table>
    </div>


    <button class="butt waves-effect waves-light right submit" name="doRegister" type="submit" id="doRegister" value="Register">Submit
      <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="butt previous action-button left" value="Previous" />


  </fieldset>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You yould call next step if the form is validated, like this:

```
$("#myForm").validate({

    success: function(label) {

        if ($("#myForm").valid()) {
            runMyFunction();
        }

    },

    rules: {
        //...
    }

});
```